# What are different ways to deploy Quarkus Application?

Tags: quarkus

I have also created standalone application and executed program successfully.

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.1.1.Final:dev (default-cli) @ monitoring ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
2020-01-08 09:48:30,248 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) monitoring 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (running on Quarkus 1.1.1.Final) started in 3.090s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2020-01-08 09:48:30,266 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2020-01-08 09:48:30,267 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, mailer, resteasy, vertx]
```

I have created an application and deployed successfully in Docker.

```
C:\Users\ei10441>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
c99fa399bb5e        quarkus-quickstart/scheduler-started   "/deployments/run-ja…"   38 hours ago        Up 38 hours         8778/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 9779/tcp   elastic_nash
```

As per official website it mentioned deployment in Kubernetes and Openshift only (https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes)

Other then this What are other available ways to deploy Quarkus Application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 basic modes that a Quarkus application can be deployed:

1. As a standard Java application (executable jar with libraries on the classpath)
2. As a [native executable](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image) which can be built using GraalVM

Based on the output snippet you posted, it looks like you're running the application as a regular Java app.

If you deploy your application as a standard Java app, then you can "deploy" Quarkus anywhere you can run an executable jar (bare metal, containers, etc).

If you do the extra step of compiling your application into a native executable (which is not mandatory BTW) then your app can only be deployed on an OS that is compatible with the native executable -- which is where containers really comes in handy.

If you put either the Java app or the native executable app inside a container, you can deploy the container anywhere that supports running containers.

Comment: When we say containers, it means any container service?
Also what is etc.here? (Bare Metal, Conatiners etc.)

Comment: Q1) Yes. Containers means anywhere you can run docker. That could be on a local machine, on a cloud container service, or on any operating system that has docker installed, which could be a virtual machine, a physical server, a rasberryPi, a cloud server.

Comment: Q2) etc means a lot of what I have said in the comment above...anywhere the java runtime environment is, or can be installed. That could be a container, could be a physcial / virtual server, a raspberry pi, a local machine, a cloud VM. If you have access to the command line to run `java -jar` then you can run the executable jar.